# Passing storage of one library to another library

Tags: solidity, storage, library

I have two libraries: `A` and `B` as well as contract `C` using them.

Library `B`, in one of its functions, needs to call a couple of functions defined for `A.Storage`.

The code below compiles, tests are passing, but I have no idea how should I interpret `storage` modifier when passing library as a parameter: `A.Storage storage a`. Is this setup safe? Am I referencing the memory of contract `C` and not creating a copy of `A.Storage`?

From what I tested, passing `A.Storage memory a` does not work, the compiler complains:

> TypeError: Member "someFuncDefinedForA" is not available in struct A.Storage memory outside of storage.

```
library A {
  struct Storage { ... }
}

library B {
  using A for A.Storage;

  struct Storage { ... }

  function myFunc(
      Storage storage self,
      A.Storage storage a // <-- ?
  ) public { 
    // (...)
    a.someFuncDefinedForA();
  }
}

contract C {
  using A for A.Storage;
  using B for B.Storage;

  A.Storage internal a;
  B.Storage internal b;

  function doIt() public {
    b.myFunc(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of solc are you using? Do both A and B define the same struct or a different one with same name? It should be possible to use either storage or memory. If the functions are public you will need the ABIEncoderV2.

Comment: solc `0.5.17`, `A` and `B` define different structs; `myFunc` is public and surprisingly solc does not complain about `ABIEncoderV2`. Maybe because it's just a library function accessed via DELEGATECALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither B nor A have storage of their own, they use the storage provided by C.

I write a code similar and it works with both `storage` and `memory`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

library A {
    
    struct S {
        uint256 a;
    }
    
    function foo(A.S memory a) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return a.a;
    }
}

library B {
    
    using A for A.S;
    
    struct T {
        uint256 b;
    }
    
    function bar(B.T memory t, A.S memory s) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return s.foo() * 1000 + t.b;
    }
}

contract C {
    using B for B.T;
    
    A.S public k;
    B.T public l;
    
    function baz() public returns (uint256) {
        k = A.S(121);
        l = B.T(333);
        return l.bar(k);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure - if I want to have `B.bar` `public` so that the code is not copied into `C` but accessed via `DELEGATECALL`, I should enable `ABIEncoderV2`?

Comment: @omnomnom With `memory` modifier both solc v0.5 and v0.6 require `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2` to compile. With `storage` modifier it is not required.